# akeeba backup with prefix database connection

Tags: sql, joomla

i use joomla to build a website ,so i use ackeebabackup to backuping th  websites.
when akeeba start backuping they export the hall data base.
Is their a solution to backup just a prefix of data base

Comment: Just a prefix of the database? What do you mean by this? Akeeba Backup takes a full of your site, so the files and full database (all tables) that is associate with that site

Answer (score 0):

In Akeeba backup go to the Control Panel,

[image: Akeeba Control Panel]

at the bottom you will find "Database Tables Exclusion" where you'll have the option to "Exclude non-core tables",

[image: Database Tables Exclusion]

that should do the trick; otherwise, you can still select manually which tables to include.